# How to find year in a string?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I try to write a custom function which is going to find a current or next year in a given string. Let's say I have a string in a `Name` column: `A2022_new_accruals.xlsx`. I need to return 1 if it's true, `null` if it's not. I wrote this function but it gives me error:

```
= if Text.Contains([Name], Date.ToText(Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow()),"yyyy")) or Text.Contains([Name], Date.ToText(Date.AddYears(Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow()),1),"yyyy")) then 1 else null
```

Error:

> Expression.Error: Cannot convert value of Function type to Date type

Comment: The error makes me think you are passing in a function object, but not actually calling the function. If `Name` is a function make sure to added open/closing para at the end of it `Name()`. Not an answer, but will maybe get you closer to what's wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
let Source = #table({"Name"},{{"A2021_new_accruals.xlsx"},{"A2022_new_accruals.xlsx"},{"A2023_new_accruals.xlsx"},{"A2024_new_accruals.xlsx"}}),
ThisYear=Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow()),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each if Text.Contains([Name],Text.From(ThisYear)) or Text.Contains([Name],Text.From(ThisYear+1)) then 1 else null)
in #"Added Custom"
```

Comment: Thanks for suppert! I've changed my function to this: `=if Text.Contains([Name], Text.From(Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow()))) or Text.Contains([Name], Text.From(Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow())+1))  then 1 else null` and it works fine :)

Comment: I don't get it, but glad it works for you

Comment: Why don't get it? Just curious

Comment: It's not a function